# htaccess redirection in wamp not working

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

The .htaccess is working properly when hosted on the server but is not working in wamp. I need to remove the need for /index.php for Codeigniter. Below is my code.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
#AllowOverride All
RewriteBase /
RedirectMatch 403 ^/(application\/cache|codeigniter|\.git|\.hg).*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
#RewriteRule ^(.*\.html)$ /cms/ [NC]
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_php5.c>
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause is I forgot to turn on rewrite_module in Apache. :-(

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Manish - in what way is this not the answer to the question?   The way I read it, the OP is answering his own question, telling us what the problem was.

Comment: It is answered @Manish... I answered my own question, there is nothing wrong with the .htaccess... I merely forgot to turn on rewrite_module in Apache